# href link to # question

Tags: html, href, location-href

I have a question about the href link, tried googling it but could not find much info on this. I have a href link like this:

```
<a href='#' onclick='openSerialWindow();return false;'><h:outputText value="#{i18n.regFindSerialNumber}" /></a>
```

previously the `#` was replaced by the page.htm that it should link to and that caused an error when user right clicked on the link and chose 'Open in new window/tab'. After replacing the page.htm with # it works fine user can even r/c and open it in new tab/window.

If user simply clicked on the link both ways above worked (the # and page.htm), so I am wondering what is the true meaning of `#`?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#` is an anchor hash and points to the top of the current page.

You can create anchors in your document like this: `<a name='anchor'></a>` and then jump to them by adding `#anchor` to the page's URL. The browser will jump to the position without reloading.

If linking to page.htm produced an error, then `page.htm` is an incorrect link.

The `href` attribute is there only as fallback in case there is no Javascript. Javascripts's `return false;` prevents execution of the link. Linking to `#` means that if javascript is turned off, nothing will happen by clicking on the link except that the browser will jump to the top of the page.

Comment: Furthermore unless something **REQUIRES** javascript to work (for instance an ajax link) you should always use the valid URL to the intended page as the `href` and the jsut return false from your onclick - that way he page degrades for those who dont have JS for some reason.

Comment: Linking to page.htm ONLY gives a 404 error when user right clicks and choses 'Open in New tab/window', if the link is simply clicked there is no error, it works just fine. whereas with the # it works both ways.

Answer (score 0):

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html

A `#` indicates a link to a [named] anchor within a page.

An `<A>` which invokes some javascript generally doesn't work with the "open in new window/tab" command.