# (X/)HTML: meaning of <a href="#">

Tags: html, spry

I would like to know the semantic meaning of Click Here. What is the meaning of the pound key in this context? I've just added a Spry Menu Bar Widget in Dreamweaver and I can see this notation in the code once the widget is added to the page. I am familiar with constructs with the pound key in a URL such as Here. and then [Click Here.](http://myhost.com/mypage#foo) in some other place in the page. Clicking on the second a element brings you to the part of the page marked "foo". However, I would like to know the meaning of Click Here as noted above. In particular, what does this construct do and how can on use it?

Thanks,

John Goche

Comment: OK, now I see a link to the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971455/href-link-to-question . It seems that the <a href="#">Click me.</a> link simply moves the page in the browser to the top of the page. Is this standard W3C functionality. Any pointers describing this behavior as standard behavior would be appreciated. Thanks, John Goche

Answer (score 5):

It's a fragment identifier just like any other link with `#`, although in this case it identifies the top of the document. `<a href="#">` is often used for links that have JavaScript attached to them.

Comment: It's sort've like the `/dev/null` or the File 13 of the world wide web. Nobody knows... Where does it goes? Being facetious, of course.

Comment: I am still somewhat puzzled. If the link has JavaScript attached to it then how does this href attribute value serve a purpose? Thanks, John Goche

Comment: Its purpose is to serve no purpose. Personally I prefer to use `javascript:void(null)` just to be absolutely clear that it serves no purpose. However, the `href` attribute is required for the `<a>` tag to be a link.

Comment: I've also seen links like http://www.helloworld.com/# , which are also puzzling (never seen this kind of link a while ago), if # stands for the top of the page then why place it after a URL. Really, does # have a different meaning in this context (the link does not take me to the top of the page after all). Thanks, JG